# How to make INTEX 3.5G (aka 普创E003) Wireless USB Modem work on Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, modem

How to install and work with INTEX 3.5G 7.2 Mbps (aka 普创E003) Wireless USB Datacard Modem on Ubuntu?

Please assist me as a Linux beginner!
Thank You

Comment: This link is showing that, it is supported by Ubuntu. Please take a look here. http://shop.airtel.com/broadband-fixed-line/intex-speed-3-5g-v-7-2-modem/p-12032-21003502110-cat--0137341.html

Comment: No, it's not officially supported. The specs given there on http://shop.airtel.com/broadband-fixed-line/intex-speed-3-5g-v-7-2-modem/p-12032-21003502110-cat--0137341.html are not correct. It seems to be for an older model **INTEX 3G**, rather than for **INTEX 3.5G**.

Answer (score 4):

### Step 1

Before plugging in your modem, check the entries in your `/dev` directory.

```
ls /dev
```

You'll find an entry named `sr0` if you have an Optical Disk drive(CD, DVD, Blu-Ray, etc.). If you have no optical drive (as in the case of NetBooks and newer machines), then the dongle's storage will appear as `sr0`, and [IntexModem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245256/how-to-make-intex-3-5g-aka-%E6%99%AE%E5%88%9Be003-wireless-usb-modem-work-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/318434#318434) binary'll work for you. If that's the case, you don't need to follow these steps. Else, plug in your modem, wait a few seconds and then repeat the `ls /dev` command to look again in `/dev` directory.

### Step 2

Inside `/dev` directory, you'll find a new entry `/sr1` along with previous `/sr0`. This is a Read Only partition present on your modem, which must be ejected everytime you plug in the dongle, for switching the modem from removable storage state to modem state.

```
eject /sr1
```

In case you had no optical drive, you'll have to run `eject /sr0` instead. Wait a few seconds and then check your Modem's USB ID:

```
lsusb
```

If everything worked as expected, it'd have turned to `20a6:1105` from the previous ID `20a6:f00e`.

### Step 3

Now you have to load the kernel module to make this device recognised as a USB modem:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x20a6 product=0x1105
```

Now that you have succesfully loaded the module, the modem will be residing at `/dev/ttyUSB0`, `/dev/ttyUSB1`, `/dev/ttyUSB2`. To check, do:

```
ls /dev | grep ttyUSB
```

If nothing turns out, then wait. It can take anywhere from 30 seconds to a whole minute. Once you are sure there are these ttyUSB entries in your `/dev`, just use your default connection client to connect. For example in Ubuntu, the Network Manager or the connection icon on top panel.

---

### Background/History:

[IntexModem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245256/how-to-make-intex-3-5g-aka-%E6%99%AE%E5%88%9Be003-wireless-usb-modem-work-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/318434#318434) binary didn't work for me and showed strange behaviors such as ejecting the Optical Drive. So I contacted the author of the [IntexModem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245256/how-to-make-intex-3-5g-aka-%E6%99%AE%E5%88%9Be003-wireless-usb-modem-work-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/318434#318434) binary - Prateek "[GunJack](https://askubuntu.com/users/197927/gunjack)" Sharma, who explained to me how the binary works. It's his reply I formulated as this answer.

Newer *usb-modeswitch* versions contain 20a6:1105 and 20a6:f00e config files by default and so you don't need to do the above steps to get it working. As a result, if you're running a recent Ubuntu release, the modem'll work 'out of box' without any extra configuration.

Comment: +1 for all the effort you put in there. How about integrating a GUI modem manager with USSD and SMS functions.

Comment: @GunJack GUI Modem Manager with USSD & SMS is already there - [Check this out!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/391320/balance-of-gsm-usb-modem-using-ussd/439625#439625) However, USSD doesn't work with **INTEX 3.5G** yet. This maybe becoz I'm using generic driver or config. Maybe we can improve and optimise the driver or config so that all feature work.

Comment: I don't think Modem Manager will work with this device. There is this Prepaid Manager widget which isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this modem does not switch automatically from a USB storage device to a USB Modem. Here is a simple solution.

Download This File [IntexModem](http://www.2shared.com/file/LXTLE23M/IntexModem.html).

Now Extract it and execute the IntexModem program. This will configure your modem to be used with Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debian, Crunchbangnor other Debian based OS.

You will have to run this program everytime you plug in the modem. To make things simpler, you can put it in /usr/local/bin directory and run it just by typing IntexModem in a terminal.

Note:- You may have to wait 1-2 minutes for your modem to be recognised in Network Manager.