# Gammu doesn't work with ussd request

Tags: usb-modem, gammu

I want to use gammu for using my web-stick, i. e.  getting information about my account and loading up my account. In other words I’m interested in sending USSD-requests  and reading the answers I get.

Info:

- system: Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (64bit)
- `Bus 001 Device 016: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem`
- usb-modeswitch: installed
- gammu 1.37.0-1build1: installed
- `.gammurc` in home directory with

  ```
   port = /dev/ttyUSB2 
   model = 
   connection = at
   synchronizetime = yes
   logfile = 
   logformat = nothing
   use_locking = 
   gammuloc =
  ```

When typing in `sudo gammu -c ${HOME}/.gammurc getussd "*100#"`   (checking my credit balance) I get something like

> no feedback within specified time. Timeout. Possibly phone disconnected.

Yet my web-stick is connected. The same happens with `sudo gammu --getallsms`.

Comment: With what exactly do you need help? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi. Well, I just want to use gammu to load up my account/checking my credit balance. Therefore I need to send USSD-requests. Yet that seems not to be possible as I get  "no feedback within specified time. Timeout. Possibly phone disconnected." Then my terminal closes.

Comment: Have you tried any of these other methods? https://askubuntu.com/questions/391320/balance-of-gsm-usb-modem-using-ussd

Comment: Hi Anwar. Tnx for the suggestion and links. I´ve tried  "modem manager gui" and I have to say it works fine and meets all my needs. Tnx again for your help. Rosika

Comment: @Rosika wait! Did modem manager gui worked for ussd?

Comment: Hi Anwar. Yes, the sending of ussd-codes works quite well. I just sent "*100#" in order to check my credit balance and I got the correct reply. But I haven´t tried loading up my account yet. However as the aforementioned code works I assume the others will also work (hopefully). Rosika