# intex 3.5g modem not detected in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, connection, modem

I use intex 3.5G modem its not recognised what I do . I refer some sites they tell download zip file from http://www.2shared.com/file/LXTLE23M/IntexModem.html site.
And what should I do ?

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/245256/how-to-make-intex-3-5g-aka-%E6%99%AE%E5%88%9Be003-wireless-usb-modem-work-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: how to execute the IntexModem program and which command used for this

Comment: If you have downloaded `intex35g-modem.deb` file, then open your terminal  and type `sudo dpkg -i intex35g-modem.deb`

Answer (score 0):

if it zero cd modem you can use it by using simple a tricks, that currently i am using.
open terminal `atrl+t` and write `sudo eject /dev/sr0`
after that you will found your modem on network connection tools. configure it using your own career settings.

or you can simply use gdebi package installer.
open terminal and type `sudo apt-get insall gdebi`
after installing this apps you can install any deb apps right click>open with gdebi package installer

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to execute the file.

Download the file to your home directory:

```
wget http://dc589.2shared.com/download/LXTLE23M/IntexModem.zip?tsid=20150809-105316-637ae546
```

Rename the file, unzip the file, and delete the zipped archive:

```
mv "IntexModem.zip?tsid=20150809-105316-637ae546" modem.zip
unzip modem.zip
rm modem.zip
```

Create an alias for the file:

```
echo "alias intex='~/IntexModem'" | tee -a ~/.bashrc;. ~/.bashrc
```

Now, run the file:

```
intex &
```

or

```
intex
```